# Jackson @JsonIgnore not working with entities from a different project

Tags: java, json, jersey, fasterxml, jackson-dataformat-xml

I have a project with jersey (1.19) and Jackson (2.4.1). I'm trying to serialize/deserialize an entity with a field annotated as @JsonIgnore. The entity is in other project, and it doesn't work (it still show the field annotated with @JsonIgnore).

But, if I move the entity inside my jersey-jackson project, it does work very well.

Any ideas about what could be happening?

Thanks a lot!!!

Here my entity

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
public class Person {

    private String id;

    @JsonIgnore 
    private String estado;  


    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public String getEstado() {
        return estado;
    }
    @JsonIgnore
    public void setEstado(String estado) {
        this.estado = estado;
    }

}
```

Comment: Smells like a classloader issue with multiple copies of the annotation class.

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to say: move. I move the entity to my project, and remove it from the external project.